# How can I access sub collection within every document in collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want an user to be able to select different types of food that will be displayed on wall (only 8 items from collection) by changing category in my app. 
I have two ideas how to do that but I do not know if they are good.

First is to get items from firestore only on selected category. Example:

```
const foodRef = db.collection("food").doc('${category}').collection('items');
```

and just get those items and then set state with those items.

This is how I do it by now and it is working good but I think it is not good because every time user change the category components must re-render and user is making unnecessary queries to firestore.

So I thought that it would be good to get all "items" from every document and store it in an object and then operate on that object based on selected category.


My problem is that I tried to get sub-collection of every document in collection but I actually do not know how to do that.

 
I tried something like that:

```
const getItems = async () => {
  let snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('food').get();
  return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.collection('items').forEach(item => item.data()))
}
```

I know it will not gonna work but I wanted to do something like that. 
 
Structure in my firestore looks like that: 
**food => [16 documents] => items => [8 documents]**

So how should I do that guys, get all the items at once or render every time user change category?

**Thanks for your time and help** in advance guys:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firestore collectionGroup to get multiple subcollections in different documents. Take a look at this link for details about collection groups.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

In your case, you could probably do something like this:

```
  const everyItems = await firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('items').get();
```

Let me know if you want more details :)

Comment: Hi, thank you man it seems like it is what I needed but can you help me and tell if should I do it by getting all elements at once from those 16 documents or it would be better to get elements from one of those 16 documents and make new queries every time user changes category so component will update query collection and re-render those elements? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Since the total number of documents you want to read is relatively low, I think it would be better to make a single request with a collection group than making multiple requests for each documents. However, if the number of document increases in the future, let's say to more than a 1000 documents, it may be better to make requests every time user changes category.

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate :)